# Spring Security With Cassandra-Authentication Failed

Tags: spring-security, cassandra

I'm Trying to authenticate user using spring security with Cassandra database. I'm getting following exception:

```
Authentication Failed: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [select userName, password from user where userName=?];
 nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: 
 No indexed columns present in by-columns clause with "equals" operator 'select userName, password from user where userName=?'
```

Here is configuration details:

security-config.xml

```
 <form-login 
     login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
     login-page="/index.xhtml"  always-use-default-target="true"
                 authentication-failure-url="/index.xhtml?error=true"
                 authentication-success-handler-ref="authenticationSuccessHandler"
                 authentication-failure-handler-ref="authenticationFailureHandler"/>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider>
            <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="cassandraDataSource" users-by-username-query="select userName, password from user where userName=?"
                               authorities-by-username-query="select roleId, userName, roleName from role where userName=?"/>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
```

and I created the index with cql command:

```
CREATE INDEX userName_index ON role (userName);
CREATE INDEX userNameUser_index ON user (userName);
```

result of desc mykeyspaces

```
CREATE TABLE role (
    roleid int PRIMARY KEY,
    rolename text,
    username text
) WITH bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = '{"keys":"ALL", "rows_per_partition":"NONE"}'
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'min_threshold': '4', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32'}
    AND compression = {'sstable_compression': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99.0PERCENTILE';
CREATE INDEX userName_index ON role (username);

CREATE TABLE user (
    userid int PRIMARY KEY,
    email text,
    firstname text,
    lastname text,
    password text,
    phone int,
    username text
) WITH bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = '{"keys":"ALL", "rows_per_partition":"NONE"}'
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'min_threshold': '4', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32'}
    AND compression = {'sstable_compression': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99.0PERCENTILE';
CREATE INDEX userNameUser_index ON user (username);

cqlsh:system>
```

Comment: What is the partition key in `user` and `role` tables? Can you do 'desc yourkeyspacename'  and post the relevant output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `user` and `role` tables for security, `username` should  be a partition key on both of those tables. Just indexing them is going to cause querying multiple nodes and not going to be effective. The data model below will be more effective for your queries.

```
CREATE TABLE user (
    userid int,
    email text,
    firstname text,
    lastname text,
    password text,
    phone int,
    username text,
    PRIMARY KEY ((username), userid)

) 

CREATE TABLE role (
    roleid int,
    rolename text,
    username text,
    PRIMARY KEY ((username), roleid)
)
```

As you can see, primary key consists of 2 columns, to insure uniqueness, but only the first one is a partition key. This insures that all records for that user will be on one node and queries by user name will be effective.

There is a lot of [info](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/basic-rules-of-cassandra-data-modeling) available about data modeling for Cassandra which differs a lot from data modeling for relational database. The basic rules are:

- Understand partition and cluster keys
- Model to your queries, not data
- Indexes are not efficient

Comment: I have another error:  Authentication Failed: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [select username, password from user where username=?]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: unable to make int from 'username' 'select username, password from user where username=?'

Comment: Did you try this query in cqlsh ? Also, according to the documentation users-by-username-query should return 3 values: username, password and enabled.

Comment: it works with cqlsh but same problem with spring security: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: unable to make int from 'username' 'select username, password, enabled from user where username=?'

Comment: try the following for users query `select userName, password from user where userName=?0` . if this does not help, consider asking a  new question